# return all model properties, even if null or empty, using IQueryable.Where method

Tags: c#, json

I have a fairly simple `HttpGet` request that returns a model by Id.

It's working, but it doesn't return model properties that are null.  It just leave them out.

I've searched and searched, but I can't find a way to get it to return every model property even if it happens to be null.

Here is my method:

```
[HttpGet("GetOptionsByMachineId/{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MachineOptions>>> GetOptionsByMachineId(Guid id)
{
    var optionsByMachine = await _context.MachineOptions.Where(q => q.MachineId == id).OrderBy(c => c.OrderId).ToListAsync();

    return optionsByMachine;
}
```

And here is the model for MachineOptions:

```
public partial class MachineOptions
{
    public Guid OptionId { get; set; }
    public Guid? PartId { get; set; }
    public string OptionText { get; set; }
    public string PartDepartment { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentManager { get; set; }
    public int? OrderId { get; set; }
}
```

Sometimes the values in the database for MachineOptions are null, but I still want the controller to return the model property as null, like this:

```
{
    "OptionId": "3ec4daad-b104-4b0f-9e5d-236bdc853a58",
    "PartId": "dfd5fb42-d47c-4445-8168-82201ddc1247",
    "OptionText": "Clear Coat",
    "PartDepartment": "Paint",
    "DepartmentManager": "" // or just say null
    "orderId": 1
}
```

But the way it is now, it just leaves any empty or null values out, in this example it's DepartmentManager, DepartmentManager is missing completely, like this:

```
{
    "OptionId": "3ec4daad-b104-4b0f-9e5d-236bdc853a58",
    "PartId": "dfd5fb42-d47c-4445-8168-82201ddc1247",
    "OptionText": "Clear Coat",
    "PartDepartment": "Paint",
    "orderId": 1
}
```

I tried looking for an overload or option for "Where", but I can't find any.

Is there way to get it to do what I need?

Thanks!

Comment: What you ask has nothing to do with EF Core or LINQ. It's the JSON serializer that decides what to emit. Which stack and version are you using? Some use Json.NET while the latest .NET Core versions use System.Text.Json

Comment: The default for both JSON.Net and System.Text.Json appears to be to include null properties. Are you setting special options somewhere?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am using .Net Core 3.1

Comment: @NetMage not that I'm aware of...in fact this code is mainly out-of-the-box code generated by Visual Studio and the .net core dbcontext command.

Comment: The [default is to *include* all null properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#exclude-properties-from-serialization). You'll find a lot of duplicates asking how to *exclude* them. Have you [set `IgnoreNullValues` in `Startup.cs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#exclude-all-null-value-properties) perhaps? Or used a custom converter?

Comment: Can you show the serialization code?

Comment: @NetMage I don't have any serialization code.  I am testing with Postman.

Comment: You must have serialization code to send the JSON through the HTTPGet API?

Comment: @NetMage honestly I haven't gotten that far yet.  I maid the controllers and I am testing them with Postman.  The JSON I used above is what I see in the Postman window when testing the GET API endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

one of the way is

```
[HttpGet("GetOptionsByMachineId/{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MachineOptions>>> GetOptionsByMachineId(Guid id)
{
    MachineOptions optionsByMachine=new MachineOptions();  
    MachineOptions = await _context.MachineOptions.Where(q => q.MachineId == id).OrderBy(c => c.OrderId).ToListAsync();
    if(MachineOptions.DepartmentManager==null)
    {
      MachineOptions.DepartmentManager="null";
    }
    return optionsByMachine;
}
```